# Obj as parameter, then returned to other function?

Tags: java

Pseudo code:

```
function A()
{
  Obj objA = new... // 
  function B(objA)
}

function B(obj test)
{
   return test;
 }

  function C()
 {
  Obj objC = use function B() to get the objA
   // do whatever with objC  
}
```

I know this is not a good way, but how do I pass the Object from function A to function C? Without making a global object... 
This is supposed to by Java code...

Comment: Why bother writing this.. pseudocode if the real code would be pretty much the same. Look at how methods work and in particular arguments and return types.

Comment: Function C can't call method function B, since it takes a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you basically just trying to store the object in the class?

```
Class Example {
  private SomeObject obj;

  public void A() {
    obj = new Obj();
  }

  public SomeObject B(SomeObject obj) {
    this.obj = obj; // save the passed instance into the object
    return obj;
  }

  public void C() {
    obj.callSomeFunction(); // it'll still exist here, as long as you called A() before C()
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am, but the object arrives in method B from "outside". So in that case I would need to duplicate it

Comment: You can store objects that are passed as parameters as well; check the edit. Also, you don't duplicate the object, you store a link to it. If you modify the object passed to B, you modify the initial object as well. This is almost always what you want, anyway.

Comment: @BakedInhalf in Java you call methods by reference, so you don't create a copy of the object, you just store a reference to the original object